# Blank email (Apple Mail) with Content-type: multipart

Tags: php, ios, email, html-email, email-attachments

I've made an 'application' in PHP that manages guests signing in and out via a kiosk. If there is a fire, a register is generated for printing. In the event that printing the register is not possible an email is also sent to key staff.

The email contains each guests name and a ***photo.*** The photo is stored as a Base64 encoded string, I have constructed the email using the header `Content-type:multipart/alternative;boundary=####` and this appeared to work well, until staff that have iPhones pointed out they receive an email with just the last photo and nothing else! I have tried using other multipart headers - `multipart/mixed` results in a blank email with all the photos as attachments (that cannot be downloaded). The email displays fine in browser and on Android phones.

Below is an example of the email code I am producing. Have I used the boundaries incorrectly? I had previously placed the images under the HTML content but I had read on SO that this can cause issues. It made no difference to Android/Web or Apple that I can tell.

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: multipart/alternative;boundary=3878aa63ed6083829fa5c76c888bf5aa
From: <no-reply@***.net>
Return-Path: no-reply@***.net
Message-ID: <***@***.***.local>
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 23 Feb 2022 09:51:49.0558 (UTC) FILETIME=[FA398D60:01D8289A]

--3878aa63ed6083829fa5c76c888bf5aa
Content-Type: image/jpg; name="Robin0.jpg"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <Robin0>
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="Robin0.jpg"


--3878aa63ed6083829fa5c76c888bf5aa
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8

<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset='utf-8'>
                <title>Visitor Register 22/02/2022</title>
            </head>
        <body>
            <div style='background:#EFEFEF;'>
                <div style='height:57px;background: #0C2D4E;'>
                    <div style='width:720px; margin:0 auto;position:relative;'>
                        <img src='https://***.net/logo.png' style='padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;'>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div style='background:white; margin:0 auto; width:720px;padding:10px;'><center><h1>Visitors on 22/02/2022</h1></center><table class='visitorTable' border='1' width='100%'>
        <thead>
            <tr style='background:#0C2D4E;text-align:center;color:white;font-weight:800;'>
                <td style='width:102px;'></td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Company</td>
                <td>Vehicle</td>
                <td>Visiting</td>
                <td style='width:75px;'>Time In</td>
                <td style='width:75px;'>Time Out</td>
                <td style='width:70px;'><span class='printonly'>Present?</span></td>
            </tr>
        </thead><tr class='' style='background:#bcffd0; '>
                        <td style='height:65px; padding:0;'><div style='height:100px; overflow:hidden;'><img class='visitorImage' style='height:100px;width:100px;' src='cid:Robin0' /></div></td>
                        <td style='padding:3px;'>Robin</td>
                        <td style='padding:3px;'>Some Company</td>
                        <td style='padding:3px;'>AB22 ABC</td>
                        <td style='padding:3px;'>Someperson</td>
                        <td style='text-align:center'>22/02/2022 15:08:26</td>
                        <td style='text-align:center'></td>
                        <td style='text-align:center'></td>
                    </tr></table></div>
                <div style='background:#4A4A49;color:white;padding:0px; margin:0px;'>
                    <div style='width: 720px;margin:0 auto;position:relative; padding:3px;'>
                    <small>Please do not reply to this email. If you have any issues, please contact the us via email <a style='color:white;' href='mailto:***@***.net'>***@***.net</a>.</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
        </html>
--3878aa63ed6083829fa5c76c888bf5aa--
```

I do not *believe* the code generating the email relates to this issue, (not directly anyway) but here is an example (somewhat sanitized):

```
$boundary=md5(uniqid(rand()));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

    if (isset($row['dateTimeOut'])) {
        $dateTimeOut = date("d/m/Y\r\nH:i:s", strtotime($row['dateTimeOut']));
        $colour = '#ffc0bc';
        $class = 'screenonly';
        $emailStyle = 'display:none;';
    } else {
        $class = '';
        $emailStyle = '';
        $dateTimeOut = '';
        $colour = '#bcffd0';
    }

    if (isset($row['dateTimeOut'])) {
        $dateTimeOut = date("d/m/Y\r\nH:i:s", strtotime($row['dateTimeOut']));
        $colour = '#ffc0bc';
    } else {
        $dateTimeOut = '';
    }

    if (empty($emailStyle)) { //Only add the row if the user is currently signed in!
        $imageName = str_replace(' ', '', $row['Name']) . $i; //Only create the file name once, it is used repeatedly

        $imageRow .= "--" . $boundary . "\r\n";
        $imageRow .= 'Content-Type: image/jpg; name="' . $imageName . '.jpg"' . "\r\n";
        $imageRow .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' . "\r\n";
        $imageRow .= 'Content-ID: <' . $imageName . '>' . "\r\n";
        $imageRow .= 'Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $imageName . '.jpg"' . "\r\n";
        //$imageRow .= 'Content-Location: '.$row['Name'].'.jpg' . "\n";
        $imageRow .= $row['Image'] . "\r\n";

        $registerRow .= "<tr class='$class' style='background:" . $colour . '; ' . $emailStyle . "'>
                    <td style='height:65px; padding:0;'><div style='height:100px; overflow:hidden;'><img class='visitorImage' style='height:100px;width:100px;' src='cid:" . $imageName . "' /></div></td>
                    <td style='padding:3px;'>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>
                    <td style='padding:3px;'>" . $row['Company'] . "</td>
                    <td style='padding:3px;'>" . $row['Registration'] . "</td>
                    <td style='padding:3px;'>" . $row['Visiting'] . "</td>
                    <td style='text-align:center'>" . date("d/m/Y\r\nH:i:s", strtotime($row['dateTimeIn'])) . "</td>
                    <td style='text-align:center'>" . $dateTimeOut . "</td>
                    <td style='text-align:center'></td>
                </tr>";
        $i++;
    }
}

$to = 'robin@***.net';
$subject = 'Visitor register for ' . date("d/m/Y", strtotime($_POST['date']));

$mailHeader = "<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset='utf-8'>
                <title>Visitor Register " . date("d/m/Y", strtotime($_POST['date'])) . "</title>
            </head>
        <body>
            <div style='background:#EFEFEF;'>
                <div style='height:57px;background: #0C2D4E;'>
                    <div style='width:720px; margin:0 auto;position:relative;'>
                        <img src='https://***.net/logo.png' style='padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;'>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div style='background:white; margin:0 auto; width:720px;padding:10px;'>";

$mailFooter = "</div>
                <div style='background:#4A4A49;color:white;padding:0px; margin:0px;'>
                    <div style='width: 720px;margin:0 auto;position:relative; padding:3px;'>
                    <small>Please do not reply to this email. If you have any issues, please contact us via email <a style='color:white;' href='mailto:***@***.net'>***@***..net</a></small>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
        </html>";

$table = '<table>';
$table = "<table class='visitorTable' border='1' width='100%'>
        <thead>
            <tr style='background:#0C2D4E;text-align:center;color:white;font-weight:800;'>
                <td style='width:102px;'></td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Company</td>
                <td>Vehicle</td>
                <td>Visiting</td>
                <td style='width:75px;'>Time In</td>
                <td style='width:75px;'>Time Out</td>
                <td style='width:70px;'><span class='printonly'>Present?</span></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>";
$table .= $registerRow;
$table .= '</table>';

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type:multipart/alternative;boundary='. $boundary . " \r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <no-reply@***.net>' . "\r\n";

$topBoundary = 'This message requires HTML/Rich content to display.' . "\r\n";
$topBoundary .= "--" . $boundary . "\r\n";
$topBoundary .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"' . "\r\n";
$topBoundary .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit' . "\r\n";

$message = $imageRow . $topBoundary . 'Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n" . $mailHeader . "<center><h1>Visitors on " . date("d/m/Y", strtotime($_POST['date'])) . "</h1></center>" . $table . $mailFooter . "\r\n--" . $boundary . '--';

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use an established mailer library such as PHPMailer, instead of trying to assemble complex multipart content yourself.

Comment: @CBroe Is it possible to do 'string attachments' with inline images using PHPMailer? I will look into it.

Comment: https://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer-PHPMailer-PHPMailer.html#method_addStringAttachment Or, if you want to embed the image in the HTML content portion of the mail, the next one, `addStringEmbeddedImage`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried PHPMailer as suggested by @CBroe and the HTML content of the email came through to Apple Mail, however, the images were blank. I was adding them to the email using `$mail->addStringEmbeddedImage($row['Image'], $imageName, $imageName.'.jpg', "base64", "image/jpg", "inline")` and the boolean came back true - not sure what is wrong there.

I inspected the email generated by PHPMailer and saw that it uses 2 boundaries, not 1. Rather than troubleshoot the new library, I have amended my original code to use 2 and it now works in Apple Mail.

```
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type:multipart/alternative;boundary=b1_'. $boundary . " \r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit';
    $headers .= 'From: <no-reply@rydeschool.net>' . "\r\n";
    
    $topBoundary .= "--b1_" . $boundary . "\r\n";
    $topBoundary .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii' . "\r\n" . "\r\n";
    $topBoundary = 'This message requires HTML/Rich content to display.' . "\r\n" . "\r\n";
    
    $topBoundary .= "--b1_" . $boundary . "\r\n";
    $topBoundary .= 'Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="b2_' . $boundary . '"; type="text/html"' . "\r\n";
    $topBoundary .= "--b2_" . $boundary . "\r\n";
    $topBoundary .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";

    $message = $topBoundary . $mailHeader . "<center><h1>Visitors on ". date("d/m/Y", strtotime($_POST['date']))."</h1></center>" . $table . $mailFooter . "\r\n" . "\r\n" . $imageRow . "--b2_".$boundary.'--' . "\r\n" . "--b1_".$boundary.'--';

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```